# Where to place Terms of use URL in itunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

My app got metadata rejection(Auto-renewable subscription). They said to give the privacy policy and terms of use URL in the information. so i find the place of privacy policy url and gave it. May i know, where i have to place the terms of use url in iTunes connect for sent it to app store review?

I got the following line in the Appstore metadata rejection list.

- Links to Your Privacy Policy and Terms of Use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ishwarya, you have to give these url and links in your App description in App Metadata in itunes.

Write all detail about your app's Auto-renewable in-app purchase. 
eg.

1) Duration

2) Price

3) What are you offering to your customers. etc.

These are means a lot to a end user.

You can check my app's description. please check it out [miles-automatic-mileage-log](https://itunes.apple.com/pt/app/miles-automatic-mileage-log/id1111109307?l=en&mt=8)

Comment: Thanks alot for your kind reply.